# Telerik RadScriptManager conflicts with jQuery

Tags: jquery, telerik, scriptmanager

I'm using Telerik RadScriptManager to call up their .js files for one of their sliders that I am using. However I have another custom jQuery plug in that I want to implement into the page. My RadScriptManager is placed in my Master Page of my aspx website.

I have successfully altered the RadScriptManager to add a jQuery Lib and it works however I need to add jquery.min.1.7.1.js for this plug in to work.

So to sum up what I need, is a way to alter the RadScript so that it accepts external jQuery plug ins.

Here is my code of my RadScriptManager and me altering the last ScriptReference and it works. I need to add more Lib as asked above.

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
        </asp:ScriptReference>
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" 
                             Path="css/Jquery/jquery.easing.1.3.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"
                             Path="css/Jquery/jquery.min.1.7.1.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"
                             Path="css/Jquery/Service.heading.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js"
                             Path="css/Jquery/Service.heading_2.js" />    
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

I've tried doing this method:

```
<Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="css/Jquery/jquery.min.1.7.1.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="css/Jquery/Service.heading.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="css/Jquery/Service.heading_2.js" />
</Scripts>
```

However it doesn't work in IE.

Please help me get this thing working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Telerik article about disabling the internal JQuery library.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scriptmanager-disabling-embedded-jquery.html